# Wrong in-line code formatting

Tags: support, comments, markdown, inline-code

I have a problem with in-line code formatting here: *[Problems with cookies and TortoiseSVN](https://superuser.com/questions/1605285/problems-with-cookies-and-tortoisesvn/1623088#comment2477543_1623088)*

I want to make two different in line code in single comment. What I'm doing wrong?

This is how it looks currently:

[image: How it looks currently]

My *green*/*red*/*blue* markers shows what to focus on:

[image: Green Good - Red Bad - Blue Not works]

In edit mode without additional spaces:

[image: In edit mode with out additional spaces]

In edit mode with additional spaces:

[image: In edit mode with additional spaces]

Comment: That's not "quotes formatting" it's inline code.

Comment: The issue is the backslash that mess the formatting, see answer in the dupe for a way to solve this. If for some reason it doesn't solve your case let me know and I'll reopen.

Comment: The sequence `\\`` is used to denote that you want a backtick character inside inline code, which would otherwise not be possible. Your code fragment ends with a backslash character, which when combined with the backtick after it is treated as a backtick within that code fragment rather than closing the fragment.

Comment: I can't reedit my comments (5 minute time is out) please reedit them if you can, I check your suggestion on sandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't edit comments - you're going to have to delete it and repost it.

Comment: I do what you said create new comment and delete old, and the answer in the dupe do the tricks. Thanks. [Link to test in sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360556/915027)

Comment: Off topic: please edit your profile and leave the "Twitter" field blank, having "none" in there cause it to link to [this Twitter account](https://twitter.com/none) which I'm pretty sure isn't yours. :)

Comment: Related: [Why is not all the code formatted as code in my comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397944/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah, looks like cross site duplicate.